# How to use the RotationInterpolator to project one line (vector) onto another?

Tags: java, java-3d

I try to rotate a vector *A* onto another vector *B* (which have the same base point and are both of length 1) via a RotationInterpolator. Somehow I never can figure out the correct TransformAxis to do this, especially since this thing uses rotY to do the actual rotation. Looked everywhere on the web but could not find a single piece of code where someone would demonstrate this with arbitrary vectors.
Could someone show me how this is done?